# Sample conditional distribution from a Markov Chain

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, conditional-probability, markov-process

Suppose I have a Markov chain (initial distribution and transition matrix).

Using this Markov chain I can generate an arbitrary length sequences.

How can I effective sample (other than rejection sampling) on it to satisfy certain properties? For example, I want sample from the conditional distribution:

$$P(X_5,X_6|X_1=1,\cdots,X_4=1,X_7=1,\cdots,X_{10}=1)$$

Comment: Since $(X_t)$ is Markov$$P(X_5,X_6|X_1=1,\cdots,X_4=1,X_7=1,\cdots,X_{10}=1)=P(X_5,X_6|X_4=1,X_7=1)\propto P(X_5|_4=1)P(X_6|X_5)P(X_7=1|X_6)$$

Answer (score 0):

Based Xi'an's comment

$$
\begin{align}
& P(X_5,X_6 | X_1, \cdots, X_4, X_7, \cdots X_{10}) \\
& = P(X_5,X_6 |X_4, X_7) \\
& \propto P(X_5|X_4)P(X_6|X_5)P(X_7|X_6) 
\end{align}
$$